# I am looking for pre trained models for different domains. ex BioBert or FinBert

Tags: pre-trained-model

Are there any other pre trained models available for different domains apart from BioBert and FinBert

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. However, you can fine-tune a pre-trained model such as BERT, for a downstream task (NER, RE, QA). To answer your question, you will find interesting the following: SciBERT https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10676 and Bertje https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09582